# Validation Rule not working :-

Tags: validation-rule

I have these stages in my Opportunity (0-Prospecting, 1-Presentation, 2 - Scoping, 3 - Prospecting, 4 - Closed). The below VR is such that only sys-admins can lower the stage from any stage. However, it is not working for Sys-admins as well, as even they cannot change the stage. Kindly let me know where I am wrong :-

```
OR
(AND
(ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "0. Prospecting"),
Intro_Meeting_Accepted__c = FALSE),
(AND
(ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "1. Presentation"),
Sales_Process_Document_Part_A_B__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "2. Scoping"),
Sales_Process_Doc_Part_C__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "3. Proposal"),
SOW_MSA__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "4. Closing"),
PO_has_been_received__c = FALSE))
)&&
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"))&&
NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.User_Type__c, "Administrator"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the system administrator profile name in the validation rule within a separate AND function.

Example:

```
NOT($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")
```

Comment: You mean something like this?
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "4. Closing"),
PO_has_been_received__c = FALSE))
)&&
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"))&&
NOT($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")